# Clean code for sequence of map/filter/reduce functions

Tags: python

Is there a simple way to code in one line a sequence of map/filter/reduce functions?

For example instead of:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, filter(lambda x: x>0, map(lambda x: x - 1, some_list)))
```

I am looking for something like:

```
some_list.map(lambda x: x -1, a).filter(lambda x: x>0).reduce(lambda x, y: x*y)
```

Comment: Why would you wont to put so much stuff into one line? Whats wrong in have 3 lines or more?

Comment: @Marcin It is the effect of being exposed to Scala...

Comment: This is one of the weirdest things in python. You know its crazy when the equivalent java code is smaller `list.stream().map(x-> x - 1).filter(x-> x > 0).reduce((x, y)-> x * y)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`PyFunctional` lets you do exactly that after installing via `pip install PyFunctional`

```
from functional import seq

seq(some_list).map(lambda x: x -1, a).filter(lambda x: x>0).reduce(lambda x, y: x*y)
```

The package can do much more than that, which you can checkout at 
[github.com/EntilZha/PyFunctional](https://github.com/EntilZha/PyFunctional)

Answer (score 9):

If you can use foreign library, look for

https://github.com/serkanyersen/underscore.py

It is python port of [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/). Therefore you can use `chain()` method to begin `filter`, `map`, `reduce` , and get the result by `value()` method.

Using this library, you can write something like

```
from underscore import _
my_array = [10, 48, -1, 30, 20, 0]
result = _(my_array).chain().map(lambda x,*a: x - 1).filter(lambda x: x > 0).reduce(lambda x,y,*a: x*y, 1).value()
```

I tested in python 3.4.2 and seems to work fine.

Answer (score 7):

You can use your own list:

```
class Mylist(list):

    def __init__(self, l):
        list.__init__(self,l)

    def map(self, f):
        return Mylist(map(f, self[:]))
```

In this case, we just subclass the list to a new list method. Then, you can add the `map`, `filter` and `reduce` methods to the class. I have shown how to add the `map` method. The other functions will be very similar.

Note that in this case, you can chain the `map` and `filter` functions as much as you want, but the `reduce` method will generally *not* result in a list it wont be possible to chain functions anymore.

Here is an example output:

```
In [16]: xx = Mylist([1,2,3])

In [17]: xx.map(lambda m: m*2).map(lambda m: m**2)
Out[17]: [4, 16, 36]
```

Comment: I encountered this "problem" recently. I am currently using Python at work and I missed the functional syntax/style from Scala. I took the idea from @ssm and extended that to an initial version of a package that hopefully provides much of the same feel for chaining function calls over data. I am totally open to feedback and only finished the first version a little while ago: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ScalaFunctional/0.0.0 and https://github.com/EntilZha/ScalaFunctional

Answer (score 0):

[Pyterator](https://github.com/remykarem/pyterator) can do this too!

```py
from pyterator import iterate

(
    iterate(some_list)
    .map(lambda x: x-1)
    .filter(lambda x: x>0)
    .reduce(lambda x, y: x*y)
)
```

You can install it with

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/remykarem/pyterator#egg=pyterator
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention the [`streamable`](https://github.com/ebonnal/streamable) module I wrote (would love to get feedback!):

Your example would look like:

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
from typing import List
from streamable import Stream

some_iterable: List[int] = ...

# lazily operate
stream: Stream[int] = (
    Stream(lambda: some_iterable)
    .map(lambda x: x - 1)
    .filter(lambda x: x > 0)
)

# iterate
reduce(mul, stream)
```

- this is a ***typed*** module with 100% code coverage and no dependency
- the `Stream[T]` class extends `Iterable[T]`
- a stream is ***immutable***
- operations are ***lazily evaluated*** and cover concurrency, grouping/flattening, exceptions catching, rate limiting, iteration progress logging, ...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes clean code means breaking up long lines. For example:

```
sub1 = map(lambda x: x - 1, some_list)
gt0 = filter(lambda x: x>0, sub1)
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, gt0)
```

This is also an opportunity to add meaningful names if you want. If not, you might prepend an underscore to indicate that the names are unimportant (i.e. `_sub1` and `_gt0`).

#### Generator expressions

These are often easier to read than `map(lambda)` and `filter(lambda)`.

```
sub1 = (x - 1 for x in some_list)
gt0 = (x for x in sub1 if x>0)
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, gt0)
```

If you had `map(filter())`, that would be really clean as a generator expression, for example:

```
sub1_if_gt1 = (x - 1 for x in some_list if x>1)
```

For `filter(map)`, you can use a dummy second loop ([which is special-cased to be fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71989665/4518341)):

```
gt0 = (y for x in some_list for y in [x - 1] if y>0)
```