# How to add an extra middle step into a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a `list[str]` object containing timestamps in `"HH:mm"` format, e.g.

```
timestamps = ["22:58", "03:11", "12:21"]
```

I want to convert it to a `list[int]` object with the "number of minutes since midnight" values for each timestamp:

```
converted = [22*60+58, 3*60+11, 12*60+21]
```

... but I want to do it in style and use a single list comprehension to do it. A (syntactically incorrect) implementation that I naively constructed was something like:

```
def timestamps_to_minutes(timestamps: list[str]) -> list[int]:
    return [int(hh) * 60 + int(mm) for ts in timestamps for hh, mm = ts.split(":")]
```

... but this doesn't work because `for hh, mm = ts.split(":")` is not a valid syntax.

What would be the valid way of writing the same thing?

To clarify: I can see a formally satisfying solution in the form of:

```
def timestamps_to_minutes(timestamps: list[str]) -> list[int]:
    return [int(ts.split(":")[0]) * 60 + int(ts.split(":")[1]) for ts in timestamps]
```

... but this is highly inefficient and I don't want to split the string twice.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use an inner generator expression to do the splitting:

```
[int(hh)*60 + int(mm) for hh, mm in (ts.split(':') for ts in timestamps)]
```

---

Although personally, I'd rather use a helper function instead:

```
def timestamp_to_minutes(timestamp: str) -> int:
    hh, mm = timestamp.split(":")
    return int(hh)*60 + int(mm)

[timestamp_to_minutes(ts) for ts in timestamps]

# Alternative
list(map(timestamp_to_minutes, timestamps))
```

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to split string twice you can use `:=` assignment operator:

```py
timestamps = [int((s := t.split(":"))[0]) * 60 + int(s[1]) for t in timestamps]
print(timestamps)
```

Prints:

```
[1378, 191, 741]
```

---

Alternative:

```py
print([int(h) * 60 + int(m) for h, m in (t.split(":") for t in timestamps)])
```

Prints:

```
[1378, 191, 741]
```

> **Note:** `:=` is a feature of **Python 3.8+** commonly referred to as the "[walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)". Here's the [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) with the
> proposal.

Comment: Can you explain or share any guide for `:=` this assignment operator. In my 2 years career I am seeing it for the first time and it looks pretty useful.

Comment: @VishwaMittar `:=` is feature of Python 3.8+. Here's PEP with the proposal: https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/

Comment: This works, but IMHO using the walrus operator for things like this just makes the code more confusing.

Answer (score 14):

Your initial pseudocode

```
[int(hh) * 60 + int(mm) for ts in timestamps for hh, mm = ts.split(":")]
```

is pretty close to what you **can** do:

```
[int(hh) * 60 + int(mm) for ts in timestamps for hh, mm in [ts.split(':')]]
```

[In Python 3.9, expressions like this were optimized](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations) so that creating a single-element array inside a comprehension just to access its single element immediately is as fast as a simple assignment.

Comment: The optimization is interesting, thanks for the link. I find the `for y in [expr]` syntax a bit weird, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil It's not really *that* weird. `.split` returns a list of strings. We don't want to loop over those strings, 1 by 1, we want to unpack them into our loop variables (hh & mm) in one step, and making the split list the single item of a list lets us do exactly that. I guess it may not be an *obvious* idiom, but I'm not Dutch. :) When I've used this trick, I generally comment it.

Comment: @PM2Ring: "When I've used this trick, I generally comment it." We agree, then. ;)

Comment: You shouldn't have `[]` around `ts.split(':')`.

Comment: @Barmar: If you remove the `[]`, `hh` and `mm` iterate over the characters of the strings (as in `[('2', '2'), ('5', '8'), ('0', '3'), ('1', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('2', '1')]`), and the one-liner returns `[122, 308, 3, 61, 62, 121]`.

Comment: yeah, I eventually realized what he's doing

Answer (score 12):

If you use generators (as opposed to list-comprehensions) for middle-steps, the whole list will still be converted in one single pass:

```
timestamps = ["22:58", "03:11", "12:21"]

#NOTE: Use () for generators, not [].
hh_mms = (timestamp.split(':') for timestamp in timestamps)
converted = [int(hh) * 60 + int(mm) for (hh, mm) in hh_mms]

print(converted)
# [1378, 191, 741]
```

You can split the comprehension in multiple-steps, written on multiple lines, and you don't need to define any function.

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party .. but why not use datetime / timedelta to convert your time?

For "hh:mm" this may be overkill, but you can easily adjust it to more complex time strings:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import typing

def timestamps_to_minutes(timestamps: typing.List[str]) -> typing.List[any]:
    """Uses datetime.strptime to parse a datetime string and return
    minutes spent in this day."""
    return [int(((p := dt.strptime(t,"%H:%M")) - dt(p.year,p.month, p.day)
                 ).total_seconds()//60) for t in timestamps]

timestamps = ["22:58", "03:11", "12:21"]

print(timestamps_to_minutes(timestamps))
```

Outputs:

```
[1378, 191, 741]
```

Comment: Nice! I was thinking of something similar with `p.time().hour*60 + p.time().minute`

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, we could also use `operator.methodcaller`:

```
from operator import methodcaller
out = [int(h) * 60 + int(m) for h, m in map(methodcaller("split", ":"), timestamps)]
```

Output:

```
[1378, 191, 741]
```